# Nginx fails on high load with Debian10 and not with Debian9

Tags: nginx, linux-networking, load-balancing, tcp, debian-buster

We had never any problems with nginx. We use 5 nginx server as loadbalancers in front of many spring boot application servers.

We were running them for years on debian 9 with the default nginx package 1.10.3. Now we switched three of our loadbalancers to debian 10 with nginx 1.14.2. First everything runs smoothly. Then, on high load we encountered some problems. It starts with

```
2020/02/01 17:10:55 [crit] 5901#5901: *3325390 SSL_write() failed while sending to client, client: ...
2020/02/01 17:10:55 [crit] 5901#5901: *3306981 SSL_write() failed while sending to client, client: ...
```

In between we get lots of

```
2020/02/01 17:11:04 [error] 5902#5902: *3318748 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, ...
2020/02/01 17:11:04 [crit] 5902#5902: *3305656 SSL_write() failed while sending response to client, client: ...
2020/02/01 17:11:30 [error] 5911#5911: unexpected response for ocsp.int-x3.letsencrypt.org
```

It ends with

```
2020/02/01 17:11:33 [error] 5952#5952: unexpected response for ocsp.int-x3.letsencrypt.org
```

The problem does only exits for 30-120 seconds on high load and disappears afterwards.

In the kernel log we have sometimes:
Feb 1 17:11:04 kt104 kernel: [1033003.285044] TCP: request_sock_TCP: Possible SYN flooding on port 443. Sending cookies. Check SNMP counters.

But on other occasions we don't see any kernel.log messages

On both debian 9 and debian 10 servers we use the identical setup and had some TCP Tuning in place:

```
# Kernel tuning settings
# https://www.nginx.com/blog/tuning-nginx/
net.core.rmem_max=26214400
net.core.wmem_max=26214400
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem=4096 524288 26214400
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem=4096 524288 26214400
net.core.somaxconn=1000
net.core.netdev_max_backlog=5000
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog=10000
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range=16000 61000
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets=2000000
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout=30
net.core.optmem_max=20480
```

The nginx config is exactly the same, so I just show the main file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 50000;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 5000;
    multi_accept on;
    use epoll;
}

http {
    root /var/www/loadbalancer;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;
    client_max_body_size 5m;
    client_header_timeout 20s; # default 60s
    client_body_timeout 20s; # default 60s
    send_timeout 20s; # default 60s

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:100m;
    ssl_buffer_size 4k;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS';

    ssl_session_tickets on;
    ssl_session_ticket_key /etc/nginx/ssl_session_ticket.key;
    ssl_session_ticket_key /etc/nginx/ssl_session_ticket_old.key;

    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/rapidssl/intermediate-root.pem;

    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    log_format custom '$host $server_port $request_time $upstream_response_time $remote_addr "$ssl_session_reused" $upstream_addr $time_iso8601 "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent";

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log custom;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx/ levels=1:2 keys_zone=imagecache:10m     inactive=7d use_temp_path=off;
    proxy_connect_timeout 10s;
    proxy_read_timeout 20s;
    proxy_send_timeout 20s;
    proxy_next_upstream off;

    map $http_user_agent $outdated {
    default 0;
    "~MSIE [1-6]\." 1;
    "~Mozilla.*Firefox/[1-9]\." 1;
    "~Opera.*Version/[0-9]\." 1;
    "~Chrome/[0-9]\." 1;
  }

  include sites/*.conf;
}
```

The upstream timeout signals some problems with our java machines. But at the same time the debian9 nginx/loadbalancer is running fine and has no problems connecting to any of the upstream servers.
And the problems with letsencrypt and SSL_write are signaling to me some problems with nginx or TCP or whatever.
I really don't know how to debug this situation. But we can reliable reproduce it most of the times we encounter high load on debian10 servers and did never see it on debian 9.

Then I installed the stable version nginx 1.16 on debian10 to see if this is a bug in nginx which is already fixed:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.16.1
built by gcc 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1c 28 May 2019 (running with OpenSSL 1.1.1d 10 Sep 2019)
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: ...
```

But it didn't help.

It seems to be a network related problem. But we do not encouter it on the application servers. But the load is of course lower as the loadbalancer/nginx machine has to handle external and internal traffic.

It is very difficult to debug as it only happens on high load. We treid to load test the servers with ab, but we could not reproduce the problem.

Can somebody help me and give me some hints how to start further debugging of this situation?

Comment: Do you have any graphs of CPU use? It would be convenient to see things like IOWAIT, softirq, idle, nice, etc. Munin shows it well. For instance, my case recently where `atop` caused it: https://serverfault.com/q/995234/31475

Comment: BTW, I see ocsp errors. The 'Online Certificate Status Protocol' does on-line queries, in this case to Let's Encrypt. If their servers are slow, they can hold you up. Are you performing OCSP queries on your load balancers? You may not need to.

Comment: Yes, we have detailed CPU stats. 24 core amd CPU is 99.9 % idle.

Comment: Yes, we do oscp stapling. This is faster for the clients. This error shows that we have a network problem and not a problem with our upstream servers, imho.

Comment: Why are you sure that the issue is not at the upstream servers or the related connection path (e.g. firewalls)?

Comment: Hard to debug, if the listed sysctl values are properly loaded, the parameters are already increasing the values related to the kernel log entries. Eventually the high load would require even larger values.

Comment: Is ab invoked on the same host with the same limits/parameters when testing debian9/10? Is ab invoked on the host running nginx or remote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

accept_mutex changed from on to off in the default value. Setting it back to "on" and Nginx is happily running with 10k requests per second again. I guess it is a combination of multi_accept and accept_mutex which caused my troubles.

These settings are not recommended by the way and we changed to a more modern setting with reuseport etc. Follow the guidelines on the Nginx blog for your own setup. Nginx is great.